# eclipse is not including all lib files in runnable jar file it creates

Tags: java

When I try to run     the jar file creating by eclipse Iv been getting a bunch of errors.
I unarchive the jar file and saw it had 3 of the 4 lib files (all external)
The lib files are
   commen2-logging-1.2.jar
   jason-2.4.jar
   httpclient.4.5.1.jar
 httpcore-4.4.4.jar

the one that does not get included is
  commen2-logging-1.2.jar

what I did
1. removed jar files, put them all in same foil,er, added them to project again 
2. created a new project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to export your project as a runnable jar and check the choice "package required librarie into generated jar..."

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, unforchantly I'v allready done this, any other idears??????